# How do I find all my unanswered questions in all my Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I asked several questions on different accounts that have never been answered.

How can I find all these questions?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/769190/yukul%c3%a9l%c3%a9?tab=accounts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178610?accountid=769190). It is a multi database query and needs your accountid (not your userid) which you can find in the url of your [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/769190/yukul%c3%a9l%c3%a9)

The query basically selects from  posts those rows with an answercount of zero and have an owneruserid that matches a row from the users table where the accountid matches your Network account id.

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #result (site sysname
                    , hostname sysname
                    , title nvarchar(250)
                    , id integer
                    , score integer
                    , creationdate datetime
                    )

select @sql = N'insert into #result' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', name ,N''' as site
     , ''',hostname ,N'''
     , p.title
     , p.id
     , p.score
     , p.creationdate
from ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts p
inner join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.users u on
  p.owneruserid = u.id
where accountid = ##accountid:int?769190## -- Network account id 
and answercount = 0  -- No Answers
and posttypeid = 1 --Q
'),N' 
union all')
from (select convert(nvarchar(max),name) name
    -- , convert(nvarchar(max),sitename)  sitename
    -- , meta
    -- , domain
     ,  concat( 
        -- based on an idea from Glorfindel 
        -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321181
        (case sitename
        WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
        WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
        WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
        WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
        WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
        WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
        WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
        WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
        WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
        WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
        WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
        WHEN 'Mathoverflow' THEN concat((meta+'.'), sitename)
        ELSE case when sitename = domain then null else sitename end
        end +'.')
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then (meta+'.') 
           else null 
           end) 
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then concat((domain + '.'), 'com') 
           else 'net' 
           end)
        ) hostname
from (
select name
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then parsename(name,2)
  else parsename(name,1) 
  end [sitename]
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then 'meta'
  else null
  end [meta]
  , coalesce(parsename(name,3), parsename(name,2)) [domain]
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
and name not like '%_Temp%' -- for when run on Sunday
) dbs
) dbsall

exec (@sql)



select site
     , concat('https://'
       , hostname
       , '/q/'
       , id
       , '|'
       , title) as [Question]
     , score
     , creationdate
from #result
```

When run today this will be the result:

[image: SEDE Query result showing site, question, score and creationdate]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).